# android: How to get album art Image from 'Uri' using Glide?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm trying to get Image from Uri using glide but what i'm not getting an Image.

**Model class - AlbumData**

```
public class AlbumData {

private long id;
public String title;
public String description;
public Uri imageId;

public long getID() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

/*public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}
*/
public Uri getArtwork(){return imageId;}
public Bitmap getArtworkBitmap(Context ctx) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ctx.getContentResolver(), imageId);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}

public AlbumData(long id, String title, String description, Uri imageId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}}
```

**RecyclerView - AlbumRecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class AlbumRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

private final String TAG = "test1";

Songs myTab;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public List<AlbumData> list = Collections.emptyList();
Context context;

public AlbumRecyclerViewAdapter(List<AlbumData> list, Context context, Songs myTab) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    this.myTab = myTab;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View songView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.album_custom_row, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder myHolder = new CustomViewHolder(songView, context, list);
    return myHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    AlbumData album = list.get(position);

    //Use the provided View Holder on the onCreateViewHolder method to
    //Populate the current row on the RecyclerView
    holder.getItemId();
    holder.title.setText(list.get(position).title);
    holder.description.setText(list.get(position).description);
    //holder.imageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).imageId);


    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    /*try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), album.getArtwork());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // log error
    }
    */

    Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse("file://" + album.getArtwork())).asBitmap().skipMemoryCache(true).into(holder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //returns the number of elements the RecyclerView will displaye
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


//Insert a new item to the RecyclerView on a predefined position
public void insert(int position, AlbumData data) {
    list.add(position, data);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public void remove(AlbumData data) {
    int position = list.indexOf(data);
    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public static class CustomViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    ImageView imageView;
    Context context;
    List<AlbumData> list = new ArrayList<AlbumData>();

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, List<AlbumData> list)
    {
        super(itemView);

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.playList_name);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_artist);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        AlbumData list = this.list.get(position);
    }
}}
```

**Fragment class - SongFragment**

```
public class Songs extends Fragment {

final public static Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
        .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");


private MediaPlayer mp;

private Intent playIntent;
private boolean musicBound = false;

private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layoutManager";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private AlbumRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
protected List<AlbumData> songsList;

private enum LayoutManagerType {
    GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER,
    LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER
}

protected LayoutManagerType mCurrentLayoutManagerType;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize dataset, this data would usually come from a local content provider or
    // remote server.

    //fill_with_data();

    //Instantiate the list
    songsList = new ArrayList<AlbumData>();

    getSongList();

    Collections.sort(songsList, new Comparator<AlbumData>() {
        public int compare(AlbumData a, AlbumData b) {
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

}


public Songs() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container,
            false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore saved layout manager type.
        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
    }

    mAdapter = new AlbumRecyclerViewAdapter(songsList, getContext(), Songs.this);
    // Set CustomAdapter as the adapter for RecyclerView.
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    return rootView;
}


public void getSongList() {
    //retrieve song info

    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);


    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST);
        //int imageColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
        //  (MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);

        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            //int thisAlbum = (int) musicCursor.getLong(imageColumn);

            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, thisId);

            songsList.add(new AlbumData(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, albumArtUri));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        musicCursor.close();
    }
}}
```

Though I commented out the bitmap section in BindViewHolder as when i using that method, it makes recyclerView slow.
So trying to use glide but I don't know why i'm not getting image. Any help would be precious.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Uri in ImageId, get string from ImageId like below, hope it will work

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(list.get(position).imageId)
     .centerCrop()
     .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
     .crossFade()
     .into(logoIv);
```

Comment: Sorry not working ( as you didn't specified any path in load() and 'toString' cannot resolve.!

Comment: please check it now i edit little in my above answere and let me know is it working right now

Comment: Still same result. Though what I think is that there's no data to load in (.load) as I'm not trying to get that Uri in onBindViewHolder which I was doing when loading image through bitmap. So I guess I have to make an object and load that ( MediaStore...... image data ) but problem is that it use bitmap to load and then i get an error.!

Comment: check in your fragment class what are you passing here to in below line
Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, thisId);

debug the value of albumArtUri which you are passing in songcast fragment and in adapter are same

Comment: Thanx :) bud... I just had to remove that toString ( as there's no string declared in model data too )

Answer (score 0):

for simple load

```
Glide.with(this).load("uri")
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(logoIv);
```

and round imageview using glide

```
 Glide.with(this)
                .load("uri")
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .crossFade()
                .into(logoIv);
```

Comment: It just showing default Image (launcher image). I am trying to get albumArt.!

Comment: it show placeholder while loading image from url. when your image load completed then it will show album image. 
test your URI in browser.

Comment: Check URI. Is that valid or not ?

Comment: Wait..! Listen, I' trying to get AlbumArt ( as you can in code ). It's showing only launcher icon as i guess there's no path supplied to it.

Comment: you can add your URI in .load("uri") . like 

.load("www.google.com")

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(this).load(uri.getPath())
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(logoIv);
```

`uri.getPath()` should solve the issue.

Comment: check if your Uri is correct.it should work you can checkout Glide documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(new File(pictureUri.getPath())) // Uri of the picture
    .into(logoIv);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I got the answer -**

```
Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).imageId).
placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_movie).into(holder.imageView);
```